# static pointcut evaluation when it is done

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

Spring AOP weaving process is done at runtime when the request to that specific method is made then a new proxy object will be created which wraps your current object and the call is intercepted.

Am I correct with my assumption?

Second thing is if this process is runtime then what are static pointcuts? when these pointcuts are evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. A proxy is created only once at startup of the application not each time a method is called on an object. (Unless you have an AOP Scoped Proxy which is prototype scoped, but that scenario is highly unlikely).

```
@Aspect
public MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* foo.bar.MyService.foo(..)) and args(x, ..)"
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pop, MyObject x) { ... }

}
```

Given the aspect above the `execution(* foo.bar.MyService.foo(..))` is the static part of the joinpoint, it can be matched regardless of inspection of types. The `args(x, ..)` however is dynamic as it needs to be determined at runtime if the value for `x` (the first argument in this case) is of type `MyObject`.

That part cannot be determined statically but only during the actual invocation. Basically anything that depends on runtime informations is dynamic in nature.